# Compare two long Strings

Tags: java, string

I want to compare two string who have those form

> ```
> s1="1390785186301"
> s2="1390785191301"
> ```

Shall I convert them to long and then compare with `>` or there are methods?

Comment: If they're already Strings then why not just use `String#compareTo()` or `String#equals()`?

Comment: @PakkuDon He wants to know which is bigger.

Comment: What is the nature of the comparison you want to make? To see if they are equal, to compare lexically (ie as though they were in a dictionary) or to compare the converted value?

Comment: If the strings are the same length (padded on the front with zeros if necessary) and consisting only of decimal digits then doing a lexical compare will tell you which is larger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two strings, just use the compareTo method

```
if(s1.length() == s2.length()){    
    if(s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {//then s1 is greater...}
}
```

Take a look at the javadoc

[String#compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Wrong. That would give you the lexicographic order.

Comment: ah, but how do you know if thats what he wants or not :)

Comment: This works fine so long as the two strings are the same length.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks I have updated my post to check for length first

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [this natural comparator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/NaturalOrderComparator.htm), in case you are not sure, if there are digits only in your string.

Comment: Not the most efficient answer, but +1 for the useful reference in case of mixed content.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a string comparison is that in a string compare 12 comes before 9, not after it.

You will need to convert it to either a `long` (if it fits within the range of a 64 bit integer) or a `BigInteger` and then do the comparison using them.

For the long do:

```
 if (Long.parseLong(str1) > Long.parseLong(str2)) {
 }
```

or:

```
 int comparison = Long.compare(Long.parseLong(str1), Long.parseLong(str2));
```

The final option would be to do your own string comparator which scans from the start of the string comparing one digit at a time but if the strings are not equal length treats the shorter one as though it was left padded with 0.

Comment: True, "12" comes before (appears smaller than) "9".  But "12" comes after "09".  If the strings are the same length then string compare is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: @HotLicks True, but only if the strings are the same length and contain no decimal points and no thousands separators (or the same separators). It's risky to make that assumption though.

Comment: If the strings contain decimal points then parseLong won't work.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, and you will get an exception telling you so - as opposed to silently giving a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Here full ans

```
   public class Comparetion {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1="1390785186301";
        String s2="1390785191301";


        if (s1.compareTo(s2) == 0) {
            System.out.println("s1 and S2 its same");
        }
        if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) {
            System.out.println("S1 is bigger then s2");
        }
        if (s1.compareTo(s2) < 0) {
            System.out.println("S2 is less then S1");
        }
    }

}

public class Comparetion {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1="1390785186301";
        String s2="1390785191301";


        if (Long.parseLong(s1) < Long.parseLong(s2)) {
            System.out.println("s1 is less then s2");
        }
        else if(Long.parseLong(s1) > Long.parseLong(s2)){

            System.out.println("s1 is bigger then s2");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("s1 and s2 are same.");

        }
    }

}
```

two possibilities. but in the case of Compare to will get exceptional cases.

Comment: no it wont give just take s1 as 12 and s2 as 9 and that will give output it is correct.. check once. and ya for some special cases it will give bcoz there will be conversion of binary and u will get ans. so may be exceptional cases will be there.

Comment: Really? In a string comparison 1 comes before 9 and it checks one character at a time so immediately you are told that 12 comes before 9...

Comment: actually i don't know deep logic of that. but yes there is some cases where will get that condition wrong. but ya i have updated the answer.

Comment: And ya in that case u have to Compare "12" and "09" because string take first element at first. :)

Comment: If you compare equal length strings (padding with leading zeros if need be) then the string compare is perfectly sufficient -- no need to convert to numeric.

Comment: That is True. :) @HotLicks +1 for that

Answer (score -1):

```
if (new Long(s1) > new Long(s2))
    // do your thing
```

I see no reason for not creating longs for this.

Here's more info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#Long%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: That's horribly inefficient.

Comment: That may be true, but unless you have performance issues/constraints, you shall never do premature optimization. Of course, you can write per-character step by step comparators, but only if really needed. First do it, then do it right, then do it fast. :)

Comment: Of course not. But I'm not talking premature optimisation. I'm talking the fact that you are doing completely un-needed boxing and unboxing just to parse the String. Just use `Long.parseLong`, `Long.valueOf` would be better than what you have but `Long.parseLong` is better than either for this case.

Comment: The problem is in the object instantiation instead of using primitives. `Long` class static methods are here for this kind of stuff.
Edit: beaten to it :)

Comment: Ok, I guess then it's a question of principle. I would still write it like this because it's super simple, as long as it only happens few times during program execution (e.g. on a user input). But I see your point.

Comment: Why the downvote? Some people seem not to understand what high-level software engineering is all about.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you need you can check if both strings contains exactly same value with `equals` method (assuming no leading zeroes and that both numbers are represented using same notation, for instance `"101"` and `"1.01E2"` represent same value but strings are not equal).

But if you want to check which string contains *bigger* value String doesn't provide much help. It has its own `compareTo` method but it is using alphabetic order, which may fail if

- strings are not same length: just like `ab` will be placed before `b` in dictionary, same rule applies to `"12"` `"2"` which means that `12 < 2` using this order
- we are comparing negative values: example `12 < 13` in alphabetic order, but it also means `-12 < -13`.

It is much easier and safer to convert strings to proper numeric type like `Long`,  `BigInteger` or even `BigDecimal` and use appropriate methods, like `compareTo`.

Demo

```
String s1 = "1390785186301";
String s2 = "1390785191301";

System.out.println(Long.compare(Long.parseLong(s1), Long.parseLong(s2))); // -1
System.out.println(new BigInteger(s1).compareTo(new BigInteger(s2)));     // -1
```

*negative* value for `a.compareTo(b)` indicates that `a<b`, 0 that `a==b`, *positive* that `a>b`

Demo 2:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("101");
BigDecimal bigDecimal2 = new BigDecimal("1.01E2");
System.out.println(bigDecimal.equals(bigDecimal2));    // true
System.out.println(bigDecimal.compareTo(bigDecimal2)); // 0
```

Comment: @downvoter Care to leave comment? I will gladly improve my answer if you let me know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your answer looks good to me, I added an upvote to reverse the downvote.